# Eloquent - apply value from relationship to where in scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

So I have this need to check if a customer needs to be called. Customers has to be called at intervals depending on a value `days_between_calls` in a `BelongsTo` model called `SubscriberType`. I got it to work but I don't like it, maybe there is a cleaner way.

So I have a model `Subscription` with relations :

```php
public function subscriberType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubscriberType::class);
}

public function calls()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Call::class);
}
```

and a (very simplified) scope :

```php
    public function scopeNeedsCall(Builder $query) {
        $query->join('subscriber_types', 'subscriber_types.id', '=', 'subscriptions.subscriber_type_id')
            ->whereDoesntHave('calls', function(Builder $query) {
                $query->whereRaw('calls.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL days_between_calls DAY)');
            });
    }
```

Is there any cleaner way to use this `days_between_calls` field's value without manually joining its table and without writing raw sql?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there is not much that can be improved, and I do need a rawsql part here. I improved it a little anyway using https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many but that's about it.